# Django - How to get a form template to run (getting ' namespace not registered error ')

Tags: django, forms, namespaces

I am a newbie at Django.
Got Django 1.4.2 working with Python 2.7
on Windows 7.

I am following a tutorial and I need to get a form template appear
with radio buttons. Selecting a button sends data and the page should
ask you if you want to 'vote again?'. Also, if you do not select a button
 and submit the form it should show a message asking you to make a choice.

So far,
here's the HTML form:

```
<h1>{{ poll.question }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' poll.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in poll.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

Now when I type `http://localhost:8000/polls/1/` I should get the form, but instead I get the following error message:

```
NoReverseMatch at /polls/1/
u"'polls" is not a registered namespace
```

I registered polls as a namespace, see below in the project urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

To answer cathy's kind request, here's the vote url:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
)
```

.. and below I include the project folder's urls if this could help:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

)
```

And I just noticed the following error message shown on the browser (because Debug = True):

```
Error during template rendering

In template C:\Python27\Scripts\mysite\mytemplates\polls\index.html, error at line 4

u"'polls" is not a registered namespace
    {% if latest_poll_list %}
        <ul>
        {% for poll in latest_poll_list %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' poll.id %}">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>No polls are available.</p>
    {% endif %}
```

Any help to make that form run properly will be appreciated!

Comment: <form action="{% url polls:vote poll.id %}" method="post"> ......... </form> Can I see your code for your vote url?

Comment: If you remove the namespace, does it work?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: I'd tried, should have mentionned it, but nope, stil doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('polls.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index', name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', 'detail', name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', 'results', name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', 'vote', name='vote'),
)

{% url polls:detail poll.id %}
```

Comment: you mean I should remove the '  ' encircling polls:detail ?

Comment: wait... I remove the brackets '' and it works now.. I re-ran the server too... thanks cathy!

Answer (score 0):

Go to your settings.py file and check out your template loaders. You may need to switch their order.

The correct order should be:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',

)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This has nothing to do with template loaders.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `{% load url from future %}` on the top of your html file. It should fix your problem.

Comment: pardon me my lack of experience with HTML.. you mean to insert {% load url from future %} right under <ul> or above <h1>{{ poll.question }}</h1> ?

Comment: Above `<h1>{{ poll.question }}</h1>`. It should be the first string in the file. You're using Django 1.4.2 and for versions < 1.5 you have to put this string on the top of your template. This was mentioned in the end of third part the Django tutorial as I understand.

Comment: That's correct. Anyway, I removed the brackets '  ' as advised by cathy and it worked fine. You're I could have kept the brackets and include {% load url from future %}. Thanx!